# Use @Html.actionlink - Calling an actioncontroller of another View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view

I am struggling to call an action in a View to another View actioncontroller by passing to it a parameter.

This is the call from the View (I am in the index View and call the Account controller):

```
@Html.ActionLink("parameters", "MyParameters", "Account", new { email = "test" })
```

My runtime compiler is saying "cannot resolve action MyParameters" what' s wrong with it ?

This is the function from my account controller:

```
public ActionResult MyParameters(string email) {}
```

This is my route:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", 
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Paramètres par défaut
        );

    }
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
@Html.ActionLink("parameters", "MyParameters", "Account", null, new { email = "test" })
```

The overload is:

```
@Html.ActionLink("linkText", "actionName", "controller", object routeValues, object HtmlAttributes)
```

`routeValues` is for adding a query string on the link. So for example, if you wanted to add id=1 to the link, your action link would look like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("parameters", "MyParameters", "Account", new { @id = 1 }, new { email = "test" })
```

this would produce the following:

```
<a href="Account/MyParameters?id=1" email="test">parameters</a>
```

if you want email as a querystring you need to do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("parameters", "MyParameters", "Account", new { @id = 1, @email = "test" }, null)
```

this will produce:

```
<a href="Account/MyParameters?id=1&email=test">parameters</a>
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn' t work, the controller name that I want to call is 'Account' and its action name is 'MyParameters', 'parameters' is the name of my link

Comment: I edited my original response cos it was wrong. this should work now.

Comment: Hi, That' s it ! I am missing the new { @id = 1 } ! no more compile error I am testing it now

Comment: Hi, From your code '@Html.ActionLink("parameters", "MyParameters", "Account", new { @id = 1 }, new { email = "test" })', I am getting the id ok but not the email, from actioncontroller - public ActionResult MyParameters(string id, string email), email is null

Comment: Hi rudeovski, it works perfect, I  have learn' t alot from your comments...Millions thanks all

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ActionLink` overload that takes 3 strings and an object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505040

The code is probably trying to interpret `"Account"` as routeValues and your parameters as htmlAttributes. I'm guessing if you take a look at the link that's actually output you'll see it doesn't look like you'd expect.

Comment: Hi, how can I do it ? I tried @Html.ActionLink("parameters", "MyParameters", new { email = "test" }), may be I need to change something in the route ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> @Html.ActionLink("Controller", "Action", new { email = "test",
>   parameters = "parameters" })

Your controller:

> public ActionResult MyParameters(string email, string parameters) {}